# Select a class except another class in jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

I would like to select an element which has .handle class but does not have .exception class-

HTML-

```
<div class="handle exception">  One <div>
<div class="handle">  Two <div>

$(document).on('click', '.handle', function (e) {
   //I want to select only 2nd div.
});
```

Any help?

Comment: `.handle:not(.exception)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `:not` selector

```
$(document).on('click', '.handle:not(.exception)', function (e) {
   //I want to select only 2nd div.
});
```

or to select the 2nd .handle class element you can use `:eq(1)` or `nth-child(2)`

```
'.handle:eq(1)'  // index start from 0 so 1 to select 2nd one
'.handle:nth-child(2)'  // index start from 1 so 2 to select 2nd one
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.not` to unselect a particular class

**For example**

`$(".handle").not(".exception")...`

In Your case , it will be as mentioned in @Mohamed-Yousef 's answer

Comment: OP needs a selector, that can be passed as second parameter to `.on`.